# Karma/Jasmine/Vue/Sinon unit tests - mock a Vue child component?

Tags: vue.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, vuejs2, sinon

I would like to test my Parent component independently of its Child components:

**Parent.vue**

```
<template><div>
    Hello World
    <child></child>
</div></template>

<script>
    import Child from './Child.vue'

    export default {
        components: {Child}
    }
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template><div>Child</div></template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

**parent.spec.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Parent from '../components/Parent.vue'

describe('Parent', () => {

    it('should show mocked child', function () {
        const Child = {
            template: '<div>Mocked</div>'
        }

        const vm = new Vue({
            template: '<parent></parent>',
            components: {Parent, Child},
        }).$mount();

        expect(vm.$el.textContent).not.toContain('Child')
        expect(vm.$el.textContent).toContain('Mocked')
    });
});
```

**Failing result**

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Parent should show mocked child FAILED
    Expected '
        Hello World
        Child' not to contain 'Child'.
    webpack:///resources/assets/js/tests/parent.spec.js:16:49 <- tests/parent.spec.js:9880:49
    Expected '
        Hello World
        Child' to contain 'Mocked'.
    webpack:///resources/assets/js/tests/parent.spec.js:17:45 <- tests/parent.spec.js:9881:45
```

Comment: jexordexan on vueslack just posted this -- looks promising: https://jackmellis.gitbooks.io/vuenit/content/stubcomponents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shallow rendering to test a Vue component independently.

There are several Vue helper libraries with shallow rendering -- here's an example with `vue-init` (https://github.com/wrseward/vue-unit#shallow):

```
import { mount, shallow, beforeEachHooks, afterEachHooks } from 'vue-unit'
import Parent from '../components/Parent.vue'

describe('Parent', () => {

    beforeEach(beforeEachHooks)

    it('should show mocked child', function () {
        const vm = shallow(Parent)

        expect(vm.$el.textContent).toContain('Hello World')
        expect(vm.$el.textContent).not.toContain('Child')
    });

    afterEach(afterEachHooks)
});
```

If you need the ability to actually replace the component with a mock as in my original question, see the [vuenit library's stubComponents method](https://jackmellis.gitbooks.io/vuenit/content/stubcomponents.html), which I was also able to get working -- the critical line is `const vm = mount(Parent, {stubComponents: '<div>Mocked</div>'})`.

Interestingly, the [Vue.js unit testing documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html) claims that they may one day add such test helpers to core:

> We are planning to work on a collection of common test helpers that makes it even simpler to render components with different constraints (e.g. shallow rendering that ignores child components) and assert their output.`